# Pressing ctrl and shift not work stands .ahk

Tags: autohotkey, ctrl

I'm using this code. I play counter, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> .ahk does not work. game in <kbd>Crtl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> work for what I need to add.

```
capslock::Suspend
f2::ExitApp


~LButton::  ; while holding Left mouse button, usually fire
loop ; preform this and loop it while the fire button is held
{
    GetKeyState,updn, LButton, P ; check to see if its down
    if updn = U ; if its not down
        break ; break the loop 
    MouseClick, left,,, 2, 0, D ; if the loop isnt broken this
    MouseClick, left,,, 1, 0, U ; virtually send 2 downclicks then 1 up very fast
    DllCall("mouse_event", uint, 1, int, 0, int, 1, uint, 0, int, 1) ; on the down click move the mouse position this much
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the modifyer wild card `*` to your hotkey and it will still work if you hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>

```
~*LButton::
```

Hope it helps